# Can a drop down list open automatically upon entering the field?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, dropdown, datasheet

I have a list in a datasheet view with a drop down on the 3rd field.
When I navigate into the 3rd field I want the list to open.   The reason for this is beacuse the user is entering data via a barcode scanner.  When the user uses the keyboard ( ALT + arrow down) then scans, the field behaves fine.  If the user tries scanning without the dropdown being opened extra selections from the dropdown get entered and gets messed up.

Sharepoint 2016 Sharepoint Designer 2013

Comment: so he has some applications which scans online and saving barcode to the dropdown?

Comment: No, not entering an actual barcode. Just using a barcode scanner to scan a barcode which then enters the data into the list field so that the user doesnt have to type it.    But I dont want to get hung up on the barcode aspect.  I want to know if there is a way to have a drop down field open once you navigate into the field.